# R - Normalize values (based on some of the values)

Tags: r, normalization

I want to normalize data in R but not in a specific range (e.g. 0 to 1). I have a table like the following:

```
 benchmark  |   technique     | ipc
correlation | no_compression  | 0.5
correlation | compression-bdi | 0.6
  trisolv   | no_compression  | 0.6
  trisolv   | compression-bdi | 0.7
```

I want the IPC value of no_compression for every benchmark to be 1. The remaining techniques for a specific benchmark will be based on that no_compression value. So for example, the IPC value for compression-bdi for correlation would be 1.2.

Is there any function that I could use? I can only find mentions of normalizing to a certain range.

Comment: This would just be division. - 0.6/0.5 is 1.2.

Comment: Sure. I want to have a Normalized IPC column. It's not a question of finding the formula. The question is how to apply it in a simple way to the data frame.

Comment: Do you have an equal number of "no_compression" and non-"no_compression" rows in each `benchmark`?

Comment: I made a mistake when I was copying the benchmark names. Now it should be clear. There is only one of every technique for every benchmark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(benchmark) %>% 
  mutate(ipc_standardized = ipc / ipc[technique == 'no_compression'])
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 4
> # Groups:   benchmark [2]
>   benchmark   technique         ipc ipc_standardized
>   <chr>       <chr>           <dbl>            <dbl>
> 1 correlation no_compression    0.5             1   
> 2 correlation compression-bdi   0.6             1.2 
> 3 trisolv     no_compression    0.6             1   
> 4 trisolv     compression-bdi   0.7             1.17
> ```

Or using base R:

```
df$ipc_standarized <- unlist(lapply(
  split(df, df$benchmark), 
  function(.) .$ipc / .$ipc[.$technique == 'no_compression'])
)
```

Comment: Sorry for the possible misunderstanding, but I simplified the table. There aren't only two techniques. So the even and odd rows thing wouldn't work. Ideally, I would like to find a solution that is agnostic to the number of techniques. I assume I would have to use the name of the "no_compression" technique along grouped with the benchmark in order to produce the normalized values.

Comment: It's the "benchmark" variable. All techniques that belong to the same benchmark will be normalized to the "no_compression" technique of that benchmark. So in this case the values would be (from top to bottom) 1, 1.2, 1, 1.16.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I inadvertently copied the benchmark name 4 times. Now it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `match` which returns the index of first match to find "no_compression" `technique`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
   group_by(benchmark) %>%
   mutate(ipc = ipc/ipc[match('no_compression', technique)])

#  benchmark   technique         ipc
#  <fct>       <fct>           <dbl>
#1 correlation no_compression   1   
#2 correlation compression-bdi  1.2 
#3 trisolv     no_compression   1   
#4 trisolv     compression-bdi  1.17
```

---

Using `data.table` that would be

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, ipc := ipc/ipc[match('no_compression', technique)], benchmark]
```